# How do I pass an input response to a function in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to ask a user what they would like to do in a "shell" that Ive made.  The code that I have is as followed:

```
    /* Create a char array to hold response */
char response[80];
char exit[4] = "Exit";

printf("\n\n     Commands are as followed:");
printf("\n------------------------------------");
printf("\n'cd' 'Directory' (Changes Directorys)");
printf("\n'cp' 'FileName'  (Copys File)");
printf("\n'Exit'           (Exits the program)");
printf("\n'ls'             (Displays Info)");
printf("\n------------------------------------\n\n");

while(strcmp(exit, response) != 0){

/* Ask user for input */
fputs("$> ", stdout);

/* Flush */
fflush(stdout);

/* Make sure response is not NULL */
if ( fgets(response, sizeof response, stdin) != NULL )
{
    /* search for newline character */
    char *newline = strchr(response, '\n'); 
    if ( newline != NULL )
    {
        /* overwrite trailing newline */
        *newline = '\0'; 
    }

    actOnResponse(fs, response); 
 }
```

Now my question deals with the actOnResponse() Function.  I want to pass the response to the function.  In the function I will parse the response and string compare it to the values 'cd', 'cp' and 'ls'. But how do I pass it in? right now, when I run the program, it gives me a segmentation fault (Core Dump).

Anyone that can point out what I am doing wrong would be great! Thank you.

Here is the actOnResponse() Function:

```
void actOnResponse(int fs, char *response){

printf("%s" , response);
}
```

Comment: Please include the code for `actOnResponse`.

Comment: Where is your definition of `actOnResponse`?

Comment: What is `fs` in `actOnResponse`?

Comment: fs is just a int for the file that I am passing around, nothing important for this. And actOnResponse(); has nothing in it at the moment, its just trying to print out response.

Comment: @user3602824, it's time for you to fire up a debugger.  That will tell you what line of code is executing at the segfault and the state of the program when it happened.  `gdb` or Visual Studio are popular.

Answer (score 2):

1. initialize response, e.g. response[0] = 0.
2. exit length is 5 (there is an ending zero). Use char exit[] = "Exit"; else your strncmp might just fail.
3. fs is undefined.

This code works:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void actOnResponse(int fs, char *response){
  printf("%s\n" , response);
}

void main() {
  /* Create a char array to hold response */
  char response[80];
  char exit[] = "Exit";
  int fs = 0;

  response[0] = 0;

  printf("\n\n     Commands are as followed:");
  printf("\n------------------------------------");
  printf("\n'cd' 'Directory' (Changes Directorys)");
  printf("\n'cp' 'FileName'  (Copys File)");
  printf("\n'Exit'           (Exits the program)");
  printf("\n'ls'             (Displays Info)");
  printf("\n------------------------------------\n\n");

  while (strcmp(exit, response) != 0) {
    /* Ask user for input */
    fputs("$> ", stdout);

    /* Flush */
    fflush(stdout);

    /* Make sure response is not NULL */
    if (fgets(response, sizeof response, stdin) != NULL) {
      /* search for newline character */
      char *newline = strchr(response, '\n');
      if (newline != NULL) {
        /* overwrite trailing newline */
        *newline = '\0';
      }
      actOnResponse(fs, response);
    }
  }
}
```

(saved as `test.c`. ran `gcc -o test test.o` then `./test`).

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I fixed it within the program.  But still not what is causing the problem.

Comment: Updated, here it worked. Extra idea: You have to type 'Exit' with an uppercase E to exit, stricmp instead of strcmp might be a good idea.

Comment: What library is stricmp in? Never heard of it?

Comment: `stricmp()` described ***[here](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strcasecmp)*** `strings.h`

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rtref/stricmp.htm It's old enough to be deprecated and replaced by _stricmp according to this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235365.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Here exit[4] is not containing string end character (as it is not exit[5]) and response[80] is also not initialized and so it also not containing string ecd charecter.

So when it is used with **strcmp** and it can not find end of string and goes out of memory then you will have this segmentation fault.

So it is due to combination of both this variable.

Answer (score 0):

***Read comments in line*** for likely reason for seg fault.

The following code works:  (added missing `}` paired with `while` statement)
With following minor edits, I never saw the seg fault.

```
void actOnResponse(int fs, char *response);


int main(void)
{
    char response[80]={0};
    //char exit[>>>4<<<] = "Exit";  //seg fault may have happened resulting from this line, 
                              //need space for 5, including `\0`  Otherwise, `exit` would not
                              //be legal string, potentially cause string functions such as
                              // strcmp() or stricmp() etc. to seg fault.

    char exitt[] = "Exit";  //conflict with my system, changed `Exit` to `Exitt` throughout

    printf("\n\n     Commands are as followed:");
    printf("\n------------------------------------");
    printf("\n'cd' 'Directory' (Changes Directorys)");
    printf("\n'cp' 'FileName'  (Copys File)");
    printf("\n'Exit'           (Exits the program)");
    printf("\n'ls'             (Displays Info)");
    printf("\n------------------------------------\n\n");

    while(strcmp(exitt, response) != 0){

    /* Ask user for input */
    fputs("$> ", stdout);

    /* Flush */
    fflush(stdout);

    /* Make sure response is not NULL */
    if ( fgets(response, sizeof response, stdin) != NULL )
    {
        /* search for newline character */
        char *newline = strchr(response, '\n'); 
        if ( newline != NULL )
        {
            /* overwrite trailing newline */
            *newline = '\0'; 
        }

        actOnResponse(1, response); //not sure what 1st argument is supposed to be, just used `1`
     }
    }  //This was missing 
    return 0;
}


void actOnResponse(int fs, char *response)
{
    printf("%s" , response);
}
```